# Chat Easy Input Tools - Provides keyboard shortcuts for common text formatting commands

Tags: script, chat, keyboard-shortcuts

### About

Provides keyboard shortcuts for common text formatting commands, reducing the dependency on mouse usage. Current version does not have a configurable set of hotkeys but later versions will.

#### How to use.

*All of the following commands are run if the user has focus in the chat input area.*

- <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> inserts a link.
- <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> inserts a [site-tag](/questions/tagged/site-tag).
- <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> formats text to **bold**.
- <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> formats text to *italics*.
- <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> formats text to <strike>strike-through</strike>.
- <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> formats text to `code`.

#### License

Chat Easy Input Tools is released under the [WTFPL](http://sam.zoy.org/wtfpl/).

#### Download

You can install Chat Easy Input Tools here:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/so-chat-easy-input-tools/pnbhechmjmooppggjdlpemnagilclbcn/related

### Contact

I can be reached at `rob.lemon@gmail.com`.

### Code

Chat Easy Input Tools is written in Javascript.

The code can be retrieved from here:
https://github.com/rlemon/Chat-Easy-Input-Tools

Comment: Pro Tip: if you goto chrome://extensions and drag and drop the userscript to the page it will install it.

Comment: Make sure you download the file first.  *facepalm*

Comment: hehe yea that is important.

Comment: I want this for SO comments...

Comment: Why not use the same shortcuts the full editor on SO uses?

Comment: @ThiefMaster because I didn't think about that when I wrote it, and now I'm used to these keybindings. I will make it editable in the future ... maybe.